# Split CSV file into 6 mb files

Tags: php

I am trying to divide CSV file into 6mb files. Following is the code I have tried.

```
$file = 'upload/L_10001_20200916183801.csv';

$files = SplitCSVBySize($file, 10001);

function SplitCSVBySize($Existingfiles, $AccountId, $splitSize = "") {
  
  $fh = fopen($Existingfiles, 'r');
  $headers = fgetcsv($fh);

  $files = array();

  $filepath      = 'upload/' . 'L_' . $AccountId . '_' . date('YmdHis') . '.csv';
  $files[]       = $filepath;
  $currentFile   = $filepath;

  $outputFile = fopen($filepath, 'w');
  fputcsv($outputFile, $headers);

    $rows = 0;
    while (!feof($fh)) {
      if ($row = $rowPri = fgetcsv($fh))
      {
        
        if(filesize($filepath) < 6000000){ 
          fputcsv($outputFile, $row);
        } else {

            fclose($outputFile);
            $rows = 0;

            $filepath      =  'upload/' . 'L_' . $AccountId . '_' . date('YmdHis') . '.csv';
            $files[]       = $filepath;
            $currentFile   = $filepath;
            
            $outputFile = fopen($filepath, 'w');
            fputcsv($outputFile, $headers);

            fputcsv($outputFile, $row);
        }
        $rows++;
      } 
    }
    
    fclose($outputFile);
    fclose($fh);

  return $files;
}
```

Here challenge is I am not able to check filesize because It always returns same size as it was at very first check. Plese help here, what is wrong or any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**. function [`filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) (as well as all other derivatives from [`stat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php)) is cached. That means, once called on some file, its result will remain the same for the same file.

You need to call [`clearstatcache()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) prior to calling this function, to clear the cache.

**Second.** You don't need to call `filesize` to obtain the size of the opened file.
You can call [`fstat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php) on the opened file handle and use `'size'` item of the returned array . E.g.:

```
        ...
        $st = filestat($outputFile);
        if($st['size'] < 6000000){ 
        ...
```

**And at last** you don't need to know size of the file, since you have current file position which is, when writing to the file, equals to its size. You can use [`ftell`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php) to obtain that. I.e.

```
        ...
        if (ftell($outputFile) < 6000000) { 
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks man, It working like a champ. It is solution I was looking for.